# Как сделать tf-idf для русских текстов

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn, nlp, обработка-данных

Вопрос по поводу функции `sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer`.
Я нашел, что можно передать параметром стоп-слова. Например так:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords as nltk_stopwords

stopwords = set(nltk_stopwords.words('russian') )
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=stopwords)
tfidf_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
```

Как обрезать слова до их основ? Чтобы не было в результате одно слово в нескольких падежах отдельно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При использовании [tf-idf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) лучше лемматизировать *все* слова / токены.

Пример:

```
import os
import requests
from pathlib import Path
import nltk
from nltk import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize, regexp_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import pymorphy2
from collections import Counter


url_stopwords_ru = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stopwords-iso/stopwords-ru/master/stopwords-ru.txt"


def get_text(url, encoding='utf-8', to_lower=True):
    url = str(url)
    if url.startswith('http'):
        r = requests.get(url)
        if not r.ok:
            r.raise_for_status()
        return r.text.lower() if to_lower else r.text
    elif os.path.exists(url):
        with open(url, encoding=encoding) as f:
            return f.read().lower() if to_lower else f.read()
    else:
        raise Exception('parameter [url] can be either URL or a filename')


def normalize_tokens(tokens):
    morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()
    return [morph.parse(tok)[0].normal_form for tok in tokens]


def remove_stopwords(tokens, stopwords=None, min_length=4):
    if not stopwords:
        return tokens
    stopwords = set(stopwords)
    tokens = [tok
              for tok in tokens
              if tok not in stopwords and len(tok) >= min_length]
    return tokens


def tokenize_n_lemmatize(
    text, stopwords=None, normalize=True, 
    regexp=r'(?u)\b\w{4,}\b'):
    words = [w for sent in sent_tokenize(text)
             for w in regexp_tokenize(sent, regexp)]
    if normalize:
        words = normalize_tokens(words)
    if stopwords:
        words = remove_stopwords(words, stopwords)
    return words

stopwords_ru = get_text(url_stopwords_ru).splitlines()

url='https://www.e-reading.club/txt.php/55060/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_-_%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83.txt'
text = get_text(url)
words = tokenize_n_lemmatize(text, stopwords=stopwords_ru)
```

---

проверка:

```
In [77]: words = tokenize_n_lemmatize(text, stopwords=stopwords_ru)

In [78]: from collections import Counter

In [79]: Counter(words).most_common(20)
Out[79]:
[('роман', 235),
 ('попугай', 138),
 ('янус', 130),
 ('витька', 123),
 ('диван', 113),
 ('эдик', 107),
 ('корнеев', 94),
 ('ойра', 92),
 ('дубль', 85),
 ('нибыть', 77),
 ('модест', 76),
 ('выбегалло', 75),
 ('институт', 69),
 ('фёдор', 65),
 ('лаборатория', 56),
 ('симеон', 51),
 ('матвей', 49),
 ('горбоносый', 48),
 ('произнести', 47),
 ('хунта', 44)]
```

для сравнения - лемматизированные слова без удаления `stopwords`:

```
In [80]: words = tokenize_n_lemmatize(text)

In [81]: Counter(words).most_common(20)
Out[81]:
[('сказать', 783),
 ('быть', 623),
 ('я', 312),
 ('один', 244),
 ('роман', 235),
 ('мочь', 173),
 ('какой', 169),
 ('время', 146),
 ('человек', 145),
 ('свой', 143),
 ('который', 140),
 ('попугай', 138),
 ('янус', 130),
 ('витька', 123),
 ('себя', 121),
 ('стать', 117),
 ('очень', 116),
 ('он', 115),
 ('диван', 113),
 ('спросить', 113)]
```

---

пример работы функции лематизации:

```
In [85]: normalize_tokens("она ее ей ней неё".split())
Out[85]: ['она', 'она', 'она', 'она', 'она']
```

Comment: Спасибо, дружище